# Can minification in Google PageSped service break Adsense?

Tags: javascript, google-adsense, page-speed

A few days ago I applied for Adsense account. But it was rejected due website being down. Here is the full message:

We did not approve your application for the reasons listed below.

Issues:

- Difficult site navigation

---

Further detail:

Difficult site navigation: While reviewing your site, we found that it
was down. Google ads may not be published on a site that is not fully
launched, functioning, or easily navigable. Once your site is
functioning and has enough content for our specialists to review, we
will be happy to reconsider your application. If there is a typo in the
URL submitted, you can resubmit your application with the correct site
by following the directions below.

I monitor uptime using Pingdom. The site was not down for a single minute during this period. In fact during last month it was down for only 2 minutes.

I may have may have singled out the problem:

I'm using Google **PageSpeed** service. This service has a **JavaScript minification** option. What it did was was strip the comment and `<!-- / -->` tags from Adsense code. So the Adsense code for my site which was originally like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
/* Top Of Post */
google_ad_slot = "4962340904";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

looked like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">google_ad_client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";google_ad_slot="4962340904";google_ad_width=728;google_ad_height=90;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
```

I have disabled minification. Can someone confirm this was the problem ?

And how should I proceed with reapplication ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a very long discussion here about this:

https://www.webpagetest.org/forums/showthread.php?tid=342

Currently the advice seems to be to wait. Google is aware of the issue and is working on a solution. In the mean time you can not use the two together as Page Speed will alter the Adsense code.

One person did manage to create a workaround:

http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/non-blocking-google-adsense-ads-improve-page-speed

However it causes double impressions and there is a warning not to use it.

Comment: Your links were informative but I'm using normal Adsense code. Google now provides asynchronous code so there is no need for workarounds. Anyway what I want to ask is whether removal of `<!-- -->` tags and `/* Top Of Post */` comment messes the Adsense ?

Comment: Yes it does, the Adsense code is not allowed to be modified in any way, when the spider crawls your site it marks you in violation if it has been changed at all.